# Svg <use> tag can't fire onload methods for external source, on Firefox (angular 4 app)

Tags: javascript, svg

I've tried to add *onload* callbacks like so, but won't trigger on **Firefox**:

```
const useTAG = document.getElementsByTagName("use")[0];
useTAG.onload = () => {alert('something')}
useTAG.addEventListener('load', ()=>{ alert('something') })
```

Are there any other alternatives? But without grabbing the *href* and make another *ajax* call.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently it might be an angular issue:

I have this code in my template

```
<svg onload="alert('ok')" ><use href="/assets/icons/alert.svg#alert"></use></svg>
```

The onload method won't fire in Firefox.

**UPDATE #2**

I found that when adding svg dynamically like so:

```
let svg = document.createElement( "svg");

let use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
use.setAttribute("href", "/assets/icons/alert.svg#alert");

svg.appendChild(use);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

use.onload = () => {
  console.log("load");
};
```

**Firefox** won't fire up the load event.

it works although with innerHTML:

```
documet.body.innerHTML = '<svg onload="alert()"><use href="/assets/icons/alert.svg#alert'></use></svg>";
```

At some point, that's how angular creates nodes by its templates.

**UPDATE #3 : HACKED SOLUTION**

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<svg id='test' onload='this.onHackLoad()'><use href='/assets/icons/alert.svg#alert'></use></svg>";
        document.getElementById("test").onHackLoad = () => {
            alert("loaded")
        };
```

Comment: You'd get an onload event on the svg element when everything has loaded.

Comment: I know, that's what I want, but it doesn't trigger/work

Comment: you're putting the onload on the <use> tag, not on the <svg> tag. onload on <svg> tags does work.

Comment: I've added also (not in this example) on the SVG itself but still doesn't work. On chrome it works like so

Comment: example? do you really need an example for such trivial thing? <svg><use href="icon.svg"></use></svg>

Comment: <svg onload="alert('hi')"><use .../></svg> works for me.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that I'm using angular. I see that for simple demos it works, but not within angular templates

Comment: Which is precisely why I asked for a [mcve]

Comment: I wouldn't expected to be an angular issue after all. I will refactor my code